Issue with Updating Database Information in C++ Program
I'm encountering a problem with updating information in my database using a C++ program. Here's a brief overview of the issue:
I have a C++ program that interacts with a MySQL database. When I attempt to update information that has already been inputted into the database, I encounter unexpected behavior. Specifically, when updating the stud_lname field, the program does not input the new value but instead reads the value from the Fname field and displays it as the lname.
Here's a snippet of the relevant code:
case 3: // Update
    cout << "Enter student number to update: ";
    cin >> stud_num;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    cout << "Which fields do you want to update?" << endl;
    cout << "[1]: First Name" << endl;
    cout << "[2]: Last Name" << endl;
    cout << "[3]: Section" << endl;
    cout << "[4]: Current Year" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number corresponding to the field you want to update: ";
    cin >> ans;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    switch (ans) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter new first name: ";
            cin.getline(stud_fname, 20, '\n');
            sentence_aux = "UPDATE stud_data SET stud_fname = '%s' WHERE stud_num = %d";
            break;
        case 2: // Update last name
            cout << "Enter new last name: ";
            cin.getline(stud_lname, 20, '\n');
            sentence_aux = "UPDATE stud_data SET stud_lname = '%s' WHERE stud_num = %d";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Enter new section: ";
            cin.getline(stud_sec, 20, '\n');
            sentence_aux = "UPDATE stud_data SET stud_sec = '%s' WHERE stud_num = %d";
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Enter new current year: ";
            cin >> stud_sy;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            sentence_aux = "UPDATE stud_data SET stud_sy = %d WHERE stud_num = %d";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option." << endl;
            continue; // Return to main loop
    }

    // Assign value to additionalBuffer outside the switch statement
    additionalBuffer = (ans == 4) ? 2 * sizeof(int) : sizeof(int);

    // Allocate memory for sentence and consult
    sentence = new char[sentence_aux.length() + 1];
    strcpy(sentence, sentence_aux.c_str());

    // Allocate enough space for two placeholders if updating current year
    consult = new char[strlen(sentence) + additionalBuffer];

    // Adjust the sprintf depending on the selected option
    if (ans == 4){
        sprintf(consult, sentence, stud_sy, stud_num);
    }else{
        sprintf(consult, sentence, (ans == 3) ? stud_sec : stud_fname, stud_num);
    }
    if (mysql_ping(obj)) {
        cout << "ERROR: Impossible to connect." << endl;
        cout << mysql_error(obj) << endl;
    }

    if (mysql_query(obj, consult)) {
        cout << "ERROR: " << mysql_error(obj) << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Info updated successfully." << endl;
    }

    cout << "Debug: Last name after update: " << stud_lname << endl;

    delete[] sentence;
    delete[] consult;

    mysql_store_result(obj);
    break;


I've traced the issue to the switch statement where I handle the update operation, but I'm unsure how to resolve it.
Could someone please review my code and provide guidance on how to correctly update the stud_lname field in my database? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
